# RuntimeValueProviderError when creating a google cloud dataflow template with Apache Beam python

Tags: python, python-3.x, google-cloud-dataflow, apache-beam

I can't stage a cloud dataflow template with python 3.7. It fails on the one parametrized argument with `apache_beam.error.RuntimeValueProviderError: RuntimeValueProvider(option: input, type: str, default_value: 'gs://dataflow-samples/shakespeare/kinglear.txt') not accessible`

Staging the template with python 2.7 works fine.

I have tried running dataflow jobs with 3.7 and they work fine. Only the template staging is broken.
Is python 3.7 still not supported in dataflow templates or did the syntax for staging in python 3 change?

Here is the pipeline piece

```
class WordcountOptions(PipelineOptions):
  @classmethod
  def _add_argparse_args(cls, parser):
    parser.add_value_provider_argument(
      '--input',
      default='gs://dataflow-samples/shakespeare/kinglear.txt',
      help='Path of the file to read from',
      dest="input")

def main(argv=None):
  options = PipelineOptions(flags=argv)
  setup_options = options.view_as(SetupOptions)

  wordcount_options = options.view_as(WordcountOptions)

  with beam.Pipeline(options=setup_options) as p:
    lines = p | 'read' >> ReadFromText(wordcount_options.input)

if __name__ == '__main__':
  main()
```

Here is the full repo with the staging scripts https://github.com/firemuzzy/dataflow-templates-bug-python3

There was a previous similar issues, but am not sure how related it is since that was done in python 2.7 but my template stages fine in 2.7 but fails in 3.7

[How to create Google Cloud Dataflow Wordcount custom template in Python?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55564551/how-to-create-google-cloud-dataflow-wordcount-custom-template-in-python)

**** Stack Trace ****

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "run_pipeline.py", line 44, in <module>
    main()
  File "run_pipeline.py", line 41, in main
    lines = p | 'read' >> ReadFromText(wordcount_options.input)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/apache_beam/transforms/ptransform.py", line 906, in __ror__
    return self.transform.__ror__(pvalueish, self.label)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/apache_beam/transforms/ptransform.py", line 515, in __ror__
    result = p.apply(self, pvalueish, label)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/apache_beam/pipeline.py", line 490, in apply
    return self.apply(transform, pvalueish)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/apache_beam/pipeline.py", line 525, in apply
    pvalueish_result = self.runner.apply(transform, pvalueish, self._options)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/apache_beam/runners/runner.py", line 183, in apply
    return m(transform, input, options)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/apache_beam/runners/runner.py", line 189, in apply_PTransform
    return transform.expand(input)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/apache_beam/io/textio.py", line 542, in expand
    return pvalue.pipeline | Read(self._source)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/apache_beam/transforms/ptransform.py", line 515, in __ror__
    result = p.apply(self, pvalueish, label)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/apache_beam/pipeline.py", line 525, in apply
    pvalueish_result = self.runner.apply(transform, pvalueish, self._options)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/apache_beam/runners/runner.py", line 183, in apply
    return m(transform, input, options)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/apache_beam/runners/dataflow/dataflow_runner.py", line 1020, in apply_Read
    return self.apply_PTransform(transform, pbegin, options)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/apache_beam/runners/runner.py", line 189, in apply_PTransform
    return transform.expand(input)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/apache_beam/io/iobase.py", line 863, in expand
    return pbegin | _SDFBoundedSourceWrapper(self.source)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/apache_beam/pvalue.py", line 113, in __or__
    return self.pipeline.apply(ptransform, self)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/apache_beam/pipeline.py", line 525, in apply
    pvalueish_result = self.runner.apply(transform, pvalueish, self._options)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/apache_beam/runners/runner.py", line 183, in apply
    return m(transform, input, options)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/apache_beam/runners/runner.py", line 189, in apply_PTransform
    return transform.expand(input)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/apache_beam/io/iobase.py", line 1543, in expand
    | core.ParDo(self._create_sdf_bounded_source_dofn()))
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/apache_beam/io/iobase.py", line 1517, in _create_sdf_bounded_source_dofn
    estimated_size = source.estimate_size()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/apache_beam/options/value_provider.py", line 136, in _f
    raise error.RuntimeValueProviderError('%s not accessible' % obj)
apache_beam.error.RuntimeValueProviderError: RuntimeValueProvider(option: input, type: str, default_value: 'gs://dataflow-samples/shakespeare/kinglear.txt') not accessible
```

Comment: Can you show the stack trace?

Comment: @Pablo I added the stack trace to the post. The linked github repo has everything including the stack trace and all the code to reproduce the issue.

Comment: @mlablablab have you followed any documentation/tutorial?

Comment: @muscat I have followed google's template instructions https://cloud.google.com/dataflow/docs/guides/templates/creating-templates and have deployed multiple templates using python 2. However, as soon as I switch to python 3 staging fails. You can see my simplified example in the linked github repo. Python 2 is not an option because I need to use libraries that only work in Python 3. Either I am doing something wrong and am really not noticing it or something is wrong with dataflow templates. Either way I am very suck.

Comment: @mlablablab I don't think this is a Py2 vs 3 issue. I think this is an issue with templates in the Beam version you're using. What version is it?

Comment: Perhaps this started failing a few days ago? I see requirements.txt does not request a specific version. It may be that templates are broken on Beam 2.18.0. Could you try defining the dependency as `apache-beam[gcp]<2.18.0`?

Comment: @Pablo you rock! that did it, thank you so much. Wow it was silly of me not to check that. Will go verify this in my production code to confirm the issue is solved.

Comment: @Pablo I did more digging, turns out my python2 install was using beam '2.15.0' while python3 was using '2.18.0'. I would have thought running `pip install -r requirements` would update the Beam on python 2 to the latest but turns out I do not know python's dependency system that well.

Comment: it's easy to miss. I'm glad we could figure it out - especially as I don't think you're the only one hitting this issue : )

Answer (score 5):

Unfortunately, it looks like templates are broken on Apache Beam's Python SDK 2.18.0.

For now, the solution to this is to avoid Beam 2.18.0, so in your requirements / dependencies, define `apache-beam[gcp]<2.18.0` or `apache-beam[gcp]>2.18.0`

Comment: I have updated my filed beam bug to the 2.18.0 issues https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/BEAM-9218

Comment: Awesome. Thanks so much for the detailed report!

Comment: Changing the version of apache-beam[gcp] to 2.17.0 worked for me. Thanks!

Comment: The jira issue mentioned above is fixed now. Instead of downgrading, you can do an upgrade to 2.20.0.