# Using `add_value_provider_argument` with apache beam io functions creates "RuntimeValueProviderError"

Tags: python, apache-beam, apache-beam-io

I'm trying to create a dataflow template which takes the input parameter as a `RuntimeValue`. Following the example from [the docs](https://cloud.google.com/dataflow/docs/guides/templates/creating-templates#modifying-your-code-to-use-runtime-parameters)

```py
import re

import apache_beam as beam
from apache_beam.io import ReadFromText
from apache_beam.io import WriteToText
from apache_beam.options.pipeline_options import PipelineOptions

# [START example_wordcount_templated]
class WordcountTemplatedOptions(PipelineOptions):
  @classmethod
  def _add_argparse_args(cls, parser):
    # Use add_value_provider_argument for arguments to be templatable
    # Use add_argument as usual for non-templatable arguments
    parser.add_value_provider_argument(
        '--input', help='Path of the file to read from')
    parser.add_argument(
        '--output', required=True, help='Output file to write results to.')

pipeline_options = PipelineOptions(['--output', 'some/output_path'])
with beam.Pipeline(options=pipeline_options) as p:

  wordcount_options = pipeline_options.view_as(WordcountTemplatedOptions)
  lines = p | 'Read' >> ReadFromText(wordcount_options.input)
# [END example_wordcount_templated]
```

(taken directly from [the official snippets](https://github.com/apache/beam/blob/master/sdks/python/apache_beam/examples/snippets/snippets.py)) gives the following error when trying to create a template using the following command (with specifics filled in):

```
 python -m examples.mymodule \
    --runner DataflowRunner \
    --project YOUR_PROJECT_ID \
    --staging_location gs://YOUR_BUCKET_NAME/staging \
    --temp_location gs://YOUR_BUCKET_NAME/temp \
    --template_location gs://YOUR_BUCKET_NAME/templates/YOUR_TEMPLATE_NAME
```

```
  File "lib/python3.7/site-packages/apache_beam/options/value_provider.py", line 139, in _f                                                              
    raise error.RuntimeValueProviderError('%s not accessible' % obj)
apache_beam.error.RuntimeValueProviderError: RuntimeValueProvider(option: input, type: str, default_value: None) not
 accessible
```

The [docs](https://cloud.google.com/dataflow/docs/guides/templates/creating-templates#pipeline-io-and-runtime-parameters) also state that:

> Some I/O connectors contain methods that accept ValueProvider objects.
>   To determine support for I/O connectors and their methods, see the API
>   reference documentation for the connector. The following I/O
>   connectors accept runtime parameters:
>
> File-based IOs: textio, avroio, tfrecordio

I'm not sure why the example code is giving errors. Can someone give me a hand?

For what it's worth I'm using:

```
apache-beam = {extras = ["gcp"], version = "^2.19.0"}
```

Comment: This looks like the same issue as https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59940069/runtimevalueprovidererror-when-creating-a-google-cloud-dataflow-template-with-ap but that should've been fixed in 2.19.0. Can you try using 2.17.0 and check if it works?

Comment: @AMargheriti I went with another workaround (using lambda to get runtime vars), but I believe this is slated to be fixed in 2.20.0 .. I'll leave this open for now

Comment: Ah you're right. I meant to say that it should be fixed in 2.20.0.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This has been fixed in beam `0.20.0`, released as of [4/15/2020](https://beam.apache.org/blog/2020/04/15/beam-2.20.0.html).

Using beam.io operations such as `beam.io.ReadFromText(wordcount_options.input)` with a RuntimeValueProvider simply works. If you get the same error I got in the question, try upgrading your beam dependency version.

- The relevant JIRA issue was: [BEAM-9218](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/BEAM-9218)
- The relevant PR was: [beam#10728](https://github.com/apache/beam/pull/10728)